# Optimizely CMS 12 : Delete unused Media ,Blocks individually in PowerSlice

Tags: episerver, optimizely

I'm trying to implement **PowerSlice ** gadget in our solution. Installed PowerSlice **5.2.0 ** package.

Able to fetch unused blocks and media.

```
 public override QueryRange<IContent> ExecuteQuery(IQueryParameters parameters)
    {
        var originalContentRange = base.ExecuteQuery(parameters);
        var filteredResults = originalContentRange.Items.Where(IsNotReferenced).ToList();

        var itemRange = new ItemRange
        {
            Total = filteredResults.Count,
            Start = parameters.Range.Start,
            End = parameters.Range.End
        };

        return new ContentRange(filteredResults, itemRange);
    }

    protected bool IsNotReferenced(IContent content)
    {
        return !ContentRepository.GetReferencesToContent(content.ContentLink, false).Any();
    }
```

But I'm not seeing an option for selecting individual items and delete.

[powerslice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux43q.png)

Does this version of gadget has feasibility to have check box for selecting required items and delete them or do we need to implement additional logic.

Comment: Don't think that's part of PowerSlice - it's basically just there to find subsets of content. I don't think additional UI commands are implemented.

Comment: @TedNyberg, Is there any other package that can be used for deleting unused items, blocks.